# What sci-fi trilogy starts with a soldier being whipped for a crime on a desert planet?

Tags: story-identification

Looking to find a sci fi trilogy i read years ago but can't remember title, author or even character names.

The main character starts off as being a soldier on a distant desert planet being whipped for some crime. As the story goes on it says he lost an arm fighting against a creature. I think it might be as he's being punished the creatures attacked his camp?

Later in the trilogy he's fighting for an empire as a sargaent where the enemy has leaders that have a higher amount of metal coils on their head (I'm thinking of dreadlocks?) or similar depending on their rank.

Hoping someone can help me out!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: At the least, clarify "years ago". That could be 2 to 50 :)

Comment: I read it about 6 years ago i think

Answer (score 5):

Found it - Death's Head trilogy by David Gunn.

Comment: you can accept your own answer

Comment: 48 hours after asking. Click on the checkmark by the voting buttons (clicking early will tell you how long you have left to wait).